# Xcode build fails with the 'Realm/Realm.h' file not found error on M1 Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, realm, apple-m1

Run application after cleaning build folder fails with the `'Realm/Realm.h' file not found` error on the MacBook Pro with M1 chip. The error disappears when I run Xcode using Rosetta.
Can I fix this without needing to use Rosetta every time I clean the build folder?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Can you include more information in the question about your environment? Are you using cocoapods? If so, what version (pod --version) and also include you podfile? If not, what are you using? Homebrew? Something else? What verisons? Please update the question with details and we'll take a look. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)